# Find next valid date giving a day and time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

So I want a method where I can pass it a day of the month and a time and it will find the next valid DateTime. So if the day was September 15th and I'm looking for the 17th, it would return September 17th. But if I was looking for the 31st, it would return October 31st since September 31st does not exist.

I just tried to create a method but it doesn't take into account invalid dates:

```
def find_next_date(day, time)
  now = Time.now

  if (day == now.day && time > now.strftime("%H%M%S%N")) || day > now.day
    DateTime.new(now.year, now.month, day, time)
  else
    if now.month + 1 > 12
      year += 1
      month = 1
    else
      year = now.year
      month = now.month + 1
    end

    DateTime.new(year, month, day, time)
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to do this and it would take into account invalid dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. I didn't handle the `time` portion because I wasn't sure what kid of argument you are sending (`String` or `Time`) but this should get you on your way.

```
class DateTime
  def self.find_next_date(day,time="00:00:00+00:00")
    raise ArgumentError if day > 31 || day < 1
    current_date = Date.today
    while current_date.day != day
      current_date = current_date.next_day
    end
    DateTime.parse(current_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT#{time}"))
  end
end

DateTime.find_next_date(31)
 #=> #<DateTime: 2014-07-31T00:00:00+00:00 ((2456870j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
DateTime.find_next_date(30)
 #=> #<DateTime: 2014-07-30T00:00:00+00:00 ((2456869j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
DateTime.find_next_date(1)
 #=> #<DateTime: 2014-08-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2456871j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
DateTime.find_next_date(25)
 #=> #<DateTime: 2014-07-25T00:00:00+00:00 ((2456864j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
DateTime.find_next_date(22,"01:00:00+00:00")
 #=> #<DateTime: 2014-08-22T01:00:00+00:00 ((2456892j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
DateTime.find_next_date(32)
 #=> ArgumentError: ArgumentError
```

Seems like it should work for you although some handling for `time` should be in place

Comment: Hmmm this would give me the answer I'm looking for but I kinda don't like how it basically keeps iterating in a brute force way. But it is the only way I can think of that works right now. I'm probably going to use the next_day into my own version. Thank!

Comment: @Dragonfly I can agree with you but it seemed like the cleanest solution without over complicating things and the max iterations is around 59. I did however consider creating a range from Date.today through the (Date.today + 1.month).end_of_month but realized the iteration would be the same and far less concise and would cause issues in February Good luck.